# a line in my java code is not comprehensible

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to understand this line? I tried to transform it with "if .. else" but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
return (patient1.isEmergencyCase() == patient2.isEmergencyCase()) ? (Integer.valueOf(patient1.getId()).compareTo(patient2.getId())) : (patient1.isEmergencyCase() ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 5):

```
if (patient1.isEmergencyCase() == patient2.isEmergencyCase()) {
    return Integer.valueOf(patient1.getId()).compareTo(patient2.getId());
} else if (patient1.isEmergencyCase() ) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

In other words, it's a sorting, probably to decide which patient comes first. You would typically find such a code in a `compareTo` method, which is typically used to sort lists, in this case to define who gets "served" in which order.

It returns -1 if partient1 is "lesser/earlier/etc", which happens if both of them are emergency cases and patient1's id is lower OR if only patient1 is an emergency case, otherwise it returns 1 (or 0, is both are emergency cases and their ids are equals).

You can have a look if the concept isn't yet clear: [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (patient1.isEmergencyCase() == patient2.isEmergencyCase()) {
    return Integer.valueOf(patient1.getId()).compareTo(patient2.getId());
} else {
    if (patient1.isEmergencyCase())
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

This is what has been condensed into the nested ternary expression.

The first step in understanding is to convert the expression inside the `else` into a ternary, and then work your way outwards.

That is,

```
if (patient1.isEmergencyCase())
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
```

is equivalent to `return patient1.isEmergencyCase() ? -1 : 1`.

But this expression itself is under the `else` condition.

What the code is doing is that if both patients are emergency cases, or both are non-emergency cases, then prioritize the one whose `id` comes first (according to the `compareTo` method). If, however, one patient is an emergency case while the other is not, then prioritize the emergency patient ... quite a realistic situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like this:

```
if(patient1.isEmergencyCase() == patient2.isEmergencyCase()){
    return Integer.valueOf(patient1.getId()).compareTo(patient2.getId());
} else {
    if(patient1.isEmergencyCase()){
     return -1;
} else 
     return 1;
}
```

It's a short way to write the same thing. Put the condition to evaluate before the '?' character, the put the two condition true : false.
Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested if-else for producing output from this line....here multiple ternary operators are used ...

> ternary operator---- condition?true statement :false statement;